# Can I have variants of an app in iTunes Connect, for TestFlight testing

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

Our app has two variants (staging and production), using two different app IDs. Only the production variant will ever see the light in the App Store, but it would be great to use TestFlight for alpha-testing the staging variant, then continue with beta testing and releasing the production variant.

Is this permitted by Apple's policies, e.g. having an app in iTunes Connect that is not meant for App Store distribution, only for TestFlight testing?

Comment: Yes, you can upload specific test builds just for TestFlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can upload different variants of an app to iTunesConnect and use them in TestFlight. The only technical requirement is that each upload must have a higher build number than the last upload. However, you must be careful with this since iTunesConnect does not distinguish between each of the variants. If you are not careful, it can be easy to accidentally submit the wrong build variant to the App Store.

**Side Note:**
I would recommend avoiding using TestFlight for different build variants (like QA). That's really what Ad-Hoc builds are meant for. TestFlight is built for pre-release builds that are intended to possibly be promoted to public distribution.